# How to add an element to a null Set<class>?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, null, nullpointerexception, set

I've got a set of elements of a custom class `User`. Now I simply cannot figure out, how this class could be instantiated. I even tried it by creating another object and pulling the EMPTY set from there like this:

```
Site mySite = new Site(/*some params here*/);
User newUser = new User(/*some other params here*/);
Set<User> users = mySite.getUsers();
users.add(newUser);
mySite.setUsers(users);
```

But since `mySite.users` is `null` (not empty), I of course get a NullPointerException.

So, what is the right way? I'd be very grateful and hope this is not to vague!

Cheers,
Stacky

Comment: Is it empty or is it `null`? Those are two very different states

Comment: Make sure that `mySite.getUsers()` never returns a `null` value.

Comment: change getUsers() method, so, that it returns an empty Set<>.

Comment: I wished it was empty, but it is `null` and the reason is that `Site` and `User` have each other as a property thus depend on each other. So one will have a `null` property anyways in order to be created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not empty, it is `null`. An empty `Set` is not the same as a `Set` variable that is `null`.

Check for `null` and create a new, empty `Set` if necessary:

```
Set<User> users = mySite.getUsers();
if (users == null) {
    users = new HashSet<User>();
}
users.add(newUser);
mySite.setUsers(users);
```

Or, better, make the `mySite.getUsers()` method return an empty `Set` if necessary:

```
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    return users;
}
```

Then you would not need the `null`-check.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! `HashSet` is the keyword. I wondered, why I couldn't simply take `new Set`. Thank you and sorry for my lack of basic Java knowledge.

Comment: `Set` is an interface, you can't create instances of an interface. You have to use a concrete class that implements the interface. `HashSet` is one of the most commonly used ones, but there are also others, for example `TreeSet`. See the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 5):

There's a *huge* difference between a reference to an empty set, and a null reference. (Just like there's a huge different between a reference to the empty string, and a null reference.)

It sounds like you should probably change your `Site` class (or whatever the type of `mySite` is) so that `getUsers()` returns an empty set instead of a null reference when there are no users. In general, empty collections are easier to work with than null references - it saves constantly having to perform nullity checks.

Comment: There are some robots checking for your answers to upvote it, isn't it? :P

Answer (score 1):

```
User newUser = new User(/*some params here*/);
Set<User> users = mySite.getUsers();
//the change here
if(users == null) { user = new HashSet<User>();}

users.add(newUser);
mySite.setUsers(users);
```

by the way, this is a bad practice, `mySite.getUsers();` would have the behaviour of creating an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

mySite.users is not empty, it's null. Make sure you initialize it properly.

```
public class Site {

   private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

   public Set<User> getUsers() {
     return users;
   }

   ...

}
```

Comment: Ouch.  Beaten by Jon Skeet :)